# Редактирование данных

Tags: java, android, textview

Есть таблица с данными, уже готовыми. Как реализовать их редактирование? Чтоб они еще сохранялись при этом

```
<TableRow android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="15:35"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="ПиОА лаб"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="8216"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</TableRow>
```

В активити этого слоя:

```
package info.moralno.leti;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Friday1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friday1);
    }

}
```

Comment: куда сохранялись? ...откуда? как Вы собираетесь получать таблицу и текстовые поля без id элементов? по какому событию вы хотите их сохранять?

Comment: Это таблица с расписанием пар и аудиторий
Я сделал Редактирование этих строк, но после перехода на другой активити, они пропадают.

Comment: Автор, изучите работу с `SharedPreferences`, почитайте про `EditText`. Если нужно чтобы данные сохранялись при вводе то почитайте про `TextWatcher`

Comment: Спасибо за совет

Comment: если у вас совсем мало данных, как в примере то SharedPreferences. Если в дальнейшем будет расширение|увеличение объема данных, то вам надо поработать с SQLite - база данных

Comment: Получилось через SharedPreferences, спасибо большое.

Comment: по хорошему вам нужно сначала создать данные (лучше всего таблицы SQLite, преференсы вовсе не предназначены для такого использования), а потом уже заполнять этими данными виджеты, а не хардкорить расписание в разметку, а потом править его там.